# How to evolve LSTM model using NEAT (Neural Evolution of Augmenting Topologies)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

When it comes to LSTM models or any NN, there are no rules as to how many neurons/layers a model should have and usually you have to work your way up top perfect these parameters. But I was wondering if there is a way to let something like NEAT (Neural Evolution of Augmenting Topologies) make the evolution of the model happen, and decide for better architecture for the model with each generation.

The NEAT-Python package is: https://pypi.org/project/neat-python/

So I have two specific questions:

1. Is it possible to optimize the architecture of a LSTM model using NEAT? (based on prediction accuracy that will be manually provided to NEAT through a prediction function)
2. Is it at all possible to just use NEAT for a time-series problem like stock prediction? If so, how efficient would it be in comparison to LSTM?

Comment: It's grossly unclear whether 'NEAT' is asking about some algorithm? a package that implements it? both? provide citations to the algorithm and package(s), please. Are you simply trying to use an existing package, or asking people to help you implement an algorithm that doesn't have a package implementation(?) And the tag definition of [tag:neat] that you tagged is currently *"Neat is an open source semantic grid framework built on top of Sass and Bourbon"*, which at best is unclear and has no citation, and at worst sounds like probably the wrong thing entirely. Please edit your question.

Comment: There are only 26*3 three-letter acronyms and 26*4 four-letter acronyms, so don't assume that simply typing 'NEAT' (without any context) is unambiguous what you're referring to. Citation, citation, citation... link, URL, author's name, conference and date... (Maybe next week someone else will use NEAT in five other contexts, and/or hijack the tag... then Q&A won't even be reusable either... just a semantic soup of keywords whose meaning can't even unambiguously be determined...)

Comment: @smci thanks. I did some editing in the title and the body of the question. I have no idea if its enough though.

Comment: Not an answer, but there was a good paper last year on an algorithm for growing/shaping arbitrary topologies called LEMONADE. It could probably be retooled to discover individual cells like LSTM if that's your goal, or include LSTM as a building block if it isn't.

Comment: Mahdi_J: ok but [your revisions #4 clobbered my clarity and formatting edits #3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63237626/revisions), so I now had to make revision #5 to add them back... Also, it's strongly encouraged on SO to post some code attempt, let alone an MCVE, not just ask about writing code.

Comment: @Mahdi_J you could have a look at [NeuralFit](https://neuralfit.net/), it's a neuro-evolution package for Python. It currently does not support recurrent neural networks, but that should be added very soon.